# NEW to NodeJS :::: Node JS Http2 Module: Response not recognized by the client

Tags: node.js, http2

I am building an HTTP2 client-server communication using nodeJS. My server is built but when i try to connect to the server from chrome, i get  -

```
127.0.0.1 sent an invalid response.
ERR_INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE
```

Below is my server code. Do i need to install a self signing certificate since its an HTTP2 connection?

```
const http2 = require('node:http2');

const server = http2.createServer();

server.on('connection',(stream)=>{
    console.log("Someone connected",stream.remoteAddress);
})

server.on('error',(error) => {
    console.log("There is an error",error);
})

server.on('stream', (stream,headers,flags)=>{
    stream.respond({
        'content-type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8',
    ':status': 200
    });
   
    stream.end('<html><body><h1>Hello World</h1></body></html>');
})


server.listen(8443,'127.0.0.1',() =>{
    console.log("server listening on port 8443");
});
```

Comment: Http2 is a secured connection. I think we need certificates installed on local host for encrypted connection, I am not sure though.